# Can a system image be restored if stored on a hard drive partition?

Tags: windows-10

All articles I find about how to create and restore a system image assume the image is stored on a dedicated, separate drive (USB drive, DVD, etc).

But what if the image is 10 or 10GB in size (containing not just Windows but all the usual applications I use, which I also want when restoring my system)? Is there a simple way to restore an image stored in a folder on a hard drive partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A system image is created by a special software and this software also has to be used to write the image back to a disk.

The simplest case is an image created using `dd` - in such a case you can also write it back using `dd` to the new hard disk.

The same is true for other disk imaging software like Acronis TrueImage, Clonezilla, ...
They all have a function to "create an image" and one for "restore an image".

If you have a clean PC without OS installed you have to create a bootable media on a working PC: For dd a common Live-Linux system is sufficient, and other commercial disk imaging software typically allow to create a Rescue media (bootable CD or USB stick) from within their software.

Comment: Thanks, so let's say my system has become corrupted or horribly slow and I want to restore an image that is currently stored on some hard drive partition. You're saying that any disk imaging software (the native Windows 10 solution or any commercial one) allows to perform that without the need for a bootable media? (also what is dd please?)

Comment: @drake035 No I said they include software for creating bootable media you can use for restoring a system image. Regarding the Windows 10 integrated I don't know. I don't use it but AFAIK it is not a disk imaging software, just a file based backup. And [this is dd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)).